# passing auto as an argument and returning auto in C++

Tags: c++, templates, auto

The code below has a function with the `auto` parameter and returns `auto` as well. Is this a bad practice or just equivalent to templates?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

auto func(auto data){
    return data;
}

int main(){

    std::cout << func(50) << std::endl;
    std::cout << func("Test") << std::endl;
    std::cout << func(5.5f) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's equivalent to templates. It's merely a shorthand for `template <typename T> auto func(T data) -> decltype(data) { return data; }`

Comment: Yes it's ok. I usually have explicit parameter types so I limit what my function can accept and I only have to test for that specific type! (in this case I favor to be explicit) and I use auto for return types since that in the end can make refactoring later much more convenient.